# Quasi Linear function

Tags: functions, special-functions

I am trying to construct/find a multivariate  function that can be approximated by a linear function in a specific range of the variable ( I mean a wide ragne and not just a small nbhd) . In this case,when  studying the   sensitivity of this function in the defined range,  only first order sensitivty indexes should be taken in consideration. I would say a function as  $$f(x,y)=x+\sqrt{y}+ \cos(x)$$ is good, however such function has  no physical meaning.

Can some one help me propsing some well known  quasi linear functions  or a function that arises from  a physics problem ( for example )  in which it can be approximated linearly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What du you mean with approximation by a linear function? Every differentiable function can be approximated by a linaer function in any point.

Comment: @M.Winter  I mean that the function can be approximated by a linear function on a range (not only nbhd of a point or small interval ). Any way , I will try to edit my question to make it more clear